# Как закрыть доступ к функции из адресной строки

Tags: php, codeigniter

Работаю с CodeIgniter. Есть контроллер Controller в котором есть несколько функций - function1, function2... Первая вызывается из адресной строки, а function**2** из function1. 
**Как закрыть доступ к function2 из адресной строки???**

Comment: убрать из названия action? или как там...я не помню уже

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Судя по документции CodeIgniter, для того, чтобы функцию нельзя было вызвать из запроса, достаточно **добавить к её названию нижний прочерк**. Там же и пример:

```
function _function2(/* параметры */)
{
    /* код */
}
```

Не знаю как CodeIgniter отреагирует, но еще одным логичным решением этой задачи **может быть объявление её как `protected` или `private`**. На вызов изнутри это, само собой, не повлияет. А вот вызвать её снаружи уже не получится. Что-то вроде этого:

```
protected function function2(/* параметры */)
{
    /* код */
}
```